# I'm making a simple aop example and it does not work

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm new to java and Spring and I'm currently trying to understand aop. I'm trying to implement very simple code with my custom annotation and @After advice and for some reason it does not work, what I expected was to get on the console 1 and the 2 insted I get only 1 do any of you guys know why?

annotation

```
package Terative.Services;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

psvm

```
package Terative;


import Terative.Services.Simulation_service;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        Simulation_service mm = new Simulation_service();
        mm.metoda();
    }


}
```

aspect

```
package Terative.Services;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
@Aspect
@Component
public class Simulation_service {


    @Pointcut("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
    public void MyAnnotationMethod() {
    }

    @MyAnnotation
    public void metoda() {

        System.out.println("1");
    }


    @After("MyAnnotationMethod()")
    public void metoda2() {

        System.out.println("2");
    }


}
```

```
C:\Users\mtsge\.jdks\azul-13.0.6\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51747:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\mtsge\OneDrive\Pulpit\j\demo\target\classes;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.2\spring-boot-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.31\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.31.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.8\spring-aop-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.8\spring-beans-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.6\aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.8\spring-jdbc-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.32.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.27.0-GA\javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.22\byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.4\jaxb-runtime-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.4\txw2-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.5.2\spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.5.2\spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.8\spring-orm-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.8\spring-context-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.8\spring-tx-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.31\slf4j-api-1.7.31.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.8\spring-aspects-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.3\jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.3\jackson-annotations-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.3\jackson-core-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.2\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.48\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.48\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.48.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.48\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.8\spring-web-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.8\spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.8\spring-expression-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.25\mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.20\lombok-1.18.20.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.8\spring-core-5.3.8.jar;C:\Users\mtsge\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.8\spring-jcl-5.3.8.jar Terative.DemoApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)

2021-06-26 16:15:03.432  INFO 8188 --- [           main] Terative.DemoApplication                 : Starting DemoApplication using Java 13.0.6 on DESKTOP-61G00PJ with PID 8188 (C:\Users\mtsge\OneDrive\Pulpit\j\demo\target\classes started by mtsge in C:\Users\mtsge\OneDrive\Pulpit\j\demo)
2021-06-26 16:15:03.432  INFO 8188 --- [           main] Terative.DemoApplication                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-26 16:15:05.764  INFO 8188 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-06-26 16:15:05.800  INFO 8188 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-06-26 16:15:07.758  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-06-26 16:15:07.779  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-06-26 16:15:07.779  INFO 8188 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
2021-06-26 16:15:08.007  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-06-26 16:15:08.007  INFO 8188 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4292 ms
2021-06-26 16:15:08.462  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-06-26 16:15:08.555  INFO 8188 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-06-26 16:15:08.801  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-06-26 16:15:08.961  INFO 8188 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-06-26 16:15:09.603  INFO 8188 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-06-26 16:15:09.681  INFO 8188 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-06-26 16:15:10.478  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-06-26 16:15:10.499  INFO 8188 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-26 16:15:10.612  WARN 8188 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-06-26 16:15:11.930  INFO 8188 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-06-26 16:15:11.945  INFO 8188 --- [           main] Terative.DemoApplication                 : Started DemoApplication in 9.53 seconds (JVM running for 10.837)
1

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read. If this is more than just a playground application, please refactor it in order to adhere to Java naming conventions, e.g. lower-case package names (`Terative.Services` → `terative.services`) and camel-case class names (`Simulation_service` → `SimulationService`). Other developers might mistake your package names for class names and think that e.g. `Terative.Services.Foo` means that `Foo` is an inner class nested inside `Services` nested inside `Terative`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out advice and custom annotation can't be in the same class which is understandable given the reason for which aop was created, I moved method with custom annotation metoda() to another class and marked it ith @Bean annotation

Comment: Spring AOP aspects cannot advise themselves or other aspects due to the proxy-based nature of the AOP framework. Native AspectJ can do this, but in real world examples it does not make much sense for an aspect to advise itself. Advising other aspects might make sense, but is an advanced topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here you create the instance by your self. Spring can not use any aspect on that as it does not belong to the spring context.

```
Simulation_service mm = new Simulation_service();
mm.metoda();
```

You need to retrieve the instance from the spring context. Then invoking the method will cause the aspect to execute.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        Simulation_service mm = context.getBean(Simulation_service.class)
        mm.metoda();
    }
```

If everything else is fine tuned it will work. In every case what I describe here is a must in order to move forward.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it has helped you solve the issue

Comment: something nust still be wrong because nothing changed

Comment: 1 gets printed however?

Comment: That is only half a solution. The other half is in the OP's own answer.